# Custom batch sampler for pytorch dataloader

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am trying to write a pytorch dataloader to use variable batch size for my data based on an id column.

| id | label | feature |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 0 | 5 |

For this example data, I want to have 3 batches, all data of id==1, all of id==2, and all of id==3. I looked up some stuff and it seems that I should use a custom sampler in order to do this but I'm running into some issues.

This is my code so far for the custom sampler, I used a dict, batchIndex, to store all the indexes corresponding to each id. But this gives me some type object is not iterable error.

```
class IdSampler(Sampler):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.indexDict = batchIndex
        self.data = data
        
    def __iter__(self):
        batchKeys = list(self.indexDict.keys())
        random.shuffle(batchKeys)
        for k in batchKeys:
            yield self.data.iloc[self.indexDict[k]]
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.indexDict)

class PandasDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dataframe)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        id = torch.tensor(self.dataframe.iloc[index][0])
        features = torch.Tensor(self.dataframe.iloc[index][2:])
        label = torch.tensor(self.dataframe.iloc[index][1])
        return id, features, label
    
train_dataloader = DataLoader(PandasDataset(data), batch_sampler=IdSampler)
```

This is the error I run into

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[148], line 2
      1 i = 0
----> 2 for query_id, features, y_target in train_dataloader:
      3     print (query_id, features, y_target)
      4     i += 1

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:441, in DataLoader.__iter__(self)
    439     return self._iterator
    440 else:
--> 441     return self._get_iterator()

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:385, in DataLoader._get_iterator(self)
    383 def _get_iterator(self) -> '_BaseDataLoaderIter':
    384     if self.num_workers == 0:
--> 385         return _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter(self)
    386     else:
    387         self.check_worker_number_rationality()

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:662, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter.__init__(self, loader)
    661 def __init__(self, loader):
--> 662     super().__init__(loader)
    663     assert self._timeout == 0
    664     assert self._num_workers == 0

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:603, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__init__(self, loader)
    601 self._timeout = loader.timeout
    602 self._collate_fn = loader.collate_fn
--> 603 self._sampler_iter = iter(self._index_sampler)
    604 self._base_seed = torch.empty((), dtype=torch.int64).random_(generator=loader.generator).item()
    605 self._persistent_workers = loader.persistent_workers

TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```